# To store integer values into a file

Tags: android, for-loop, fileoutputstream

```
for (Point point : landmarks) 
{
    for (int i = 48; i <= 66; i++)
    {
        point = landmarks.get(i);
        //Log.d(TAG,"landmarks (" + landmarks.get(i) +")");
        int pointX = (int) (point.x * resizeRatio);
        int pointY = (int) (point.y * resizeRatio);

        Log.d(TAG,"My points:(" + pointX +","+ pointY +")");

        point=landmarks.get(i+1);

        int pointXX = (int) (point.x * resizeRatio);
        int pointYY = (int) (point.y * resizeRatio);

        canvas.drawLine(pointX, pointY, pointXX, pointYY, mFaceLandmardkPaint);
    }
}
```

From the above code i have to access integer values into the variables, pointX and pointY.How can in have to store these values into a file???

Comment: Have you searched _how to write data in a file_ first ? There is enough tutorial online.

Comment: String lipfile = "lip-data"; FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/"+lipfile+".txt"); try {
                       fout.write(65);
                       //fout.write(pointX);
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   } .   using this code data is write into a file as "A".The symbol representing the ASCII value 65.

Comment: So you can write in a file, what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
try{
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");

    for (int i = 48; i <= 66; i++)
    {
        point = landmarks.get(i);
        //Log.d(TAG,"landmarks (" + landmarks.get(i) +")");
        int pointX = (int) (point.x * resizeRatio);
        int pointY = (int) (point.y * resizeRatio);

        Log.d(TAG,"My points:(" + pointX +","+ pointY +")");

        point=landmarks.get(i+1);

        int pointXX = (int) (point.x * resizeRatio);
        int pointYY = (int) (point.y * resizeRatio);

        canvas.drawLine(pointX, pointY, pointXX, pointYY, mFaceLandmardkPaint);

        writer.println(pointX + ",+ pointY + ","+pointXX+","+pointYY);
    }


    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // do something
}
```